Vuetify2 grid layout
How would I implement the layout below in Vuetify2? The widths of C and D should be equal 50-50, regardless of content. The heights of A and B should wrap their contents. The height of C should stretch to fill available space. The contents of C should be scrollable, while the rest of the page should NOT be scrollable.


Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Actually, you do not have to use the vuetify layout.
Here is a layout based on vuetify2 grid system:
https://codepen.io/ramseyfeng/pen/MWMvqXM
<div id="app" class="h-full">
  <v-app id="inspire" class="h-full">
    <v-layout class="grey lighten-5 flex-column h-full border">
      <v-row class="flex-grow-0 border my-0">
        <v-col>
          A
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row class="flex-grow-1 overflow-auto my-0">
        <v-col cols="6" class="d-flex flex-column h-full border">
          <v-row class="flex-grow-0 border">
            <v-col>
              B
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
          <v-row class="flex-grow-1 overflow-auto border">
            <v-col>
              <div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>C</div><div>CA</div>
            </
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="6">
          D
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>

CSS
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
.h-full {
  height: 100%;
}
.border {
  border: 1px solid silver;
}


Thanks, this is almost exactly what I need. How do I make it so that only C scrolls, without the whole page scrolling? I updated the question.

@SoftwareDev did you open the online demo? It should only have a scrollbar on the C section. I also update the answer to include the CSS.
https://codepen.io/ramseyfeng/full/MWMvqXM
